# Github Actions workflow; GITHUB_WORKSPACE not holding docker image between two jobs

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, cicd

Hi I am using Github Actions for CI/CD to AWS-EKS, I am also storing the image into AWS-ECR
in my workflow I gave multiple jobs, among which two jobs are `build-image` and next jobs i s `push-to-ecr`. since those jobs runs on different runners(ubuntu), in `push-to-ecr` job  it is unable to find the image.

Then I planned to use `GITHUB_WORKSPACE`, I did not go with `upload-artifact` as I am dealing in same workflow. in github_workspace , if i copy image I get `permission denied`. If I save tar of image in it, in `push-to-ecr` job it says file/dir not found
I verified I was able to push in workspace in first job, still it says .tar not found

I dont want to merge my jobs.